# Black Shadows issue on Cycles Engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, transparency

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Transparent Image]
[image: Shading Properties]

Blender File: https://blend-exchange.com/b/xNR6Mv94

I'm having an issue and it's taking me weeks to solve. When I created a group of leaves from a transparent image and went to viewport shading to preview it, These black shadows appeared around them. I had the same issue earlier with a different transparent object but I solved it by putting on alpha clip and alpha blend. I attempted the same thing here but it didn't work.

​

I googled my problem and one of the solutions was to put the Transparency in Render Properties --> Light Paths to 32 but the black shadows are still there. It seems like this issue only applies to the Cycles Render Engine as when I apply the Eevee Engine, the black shadows are gone.

​

Does anyone have any idea what's happening and is there a way to fix this on the Cycles Engine?

Comment: You could have edited your original question and put your file. The weird thing is that it seems to work fine at least for me: https://zupimages.net/up/22/44/sre6.jpg

Comment: I apologize for the repost. I'm new at blender.stackexchange. I don't understand what's happening to my leaf, I looked through every nook and cranny and I still can't find the problem. Maybe it's my computer? @moonboots Was there anything that solved the issue for you?

Comment: i didn't change anything to your file, but maybe someone will understand